# Find the error on the peak value (mode) of a skewed gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, python, mode, skew-normal-distribution

I have a distribution of data that follows approximately a skewed gaussian distribution (count rate vs time). I fit the distribution with the following function in python:

```
def skew(x, sigmag, mu, alpha, c, a):
    normpdf = (1/(sigmag*np.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*np.exp(-(np.power((x-mu),2)/(2*np.power(sigmag,2))))
    normcdf = (0.5*(1+sp.erf((alpha*((x-mu)/sigmag))/(np.sqrt(2)))))
    return 2*a*normpdf*normcdf + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(skew, time, counrate, p0=[5.5, T0, 4., 0.0001, 0.01], sigma=err_flux)
y_fit = skew(time, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4])
```

With this, I can get the parameters `sigmag, mu, alpha, c, a` and their errors by calculating:

```
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
```

However, I want to find the peak of the distribution, that is NOT described by the `mu` parameter in the function, which actually returns the `mean` while the peak in the skewed gaussian is given by the `mode`.

I can calculate the `mode` by obtaining the time corresponding to the `max(y_fit)`. The question is: how do I get the error on the such calculated `mode`, given the above-explained procedure to get the maximum of the distribution?